# how to show content of latest blog post with read more link?

Tags: blog, read-more

I want to show the latest blog post content in my side bar with a read more link.

So how will I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and set `'numberposts'` to `1`. The first and only entry will contain your latest blog post as a post object.